# Concatenate h264 bytestream using cat?

Tags: video, h.264, mpeg

I need to merge few h264 files. Can I do simply trick like this:

```
cat file0.h264 file1.h264 file2.h264 > out.h264
```

All h264 has the same encoding settings, except resolution and bitrate, and has no B-frames.

I tried, and my output file playing good,

Here is output of ffmpeg:

```
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] /
0x001B), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
```

It's correct way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, mpeg transport streams can simply be concatenated as you do it.

Reference: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate